# Upload image tag source without using file input

Tags: spring-mvc

I want to upload `<img>` tag src in my spring mvc. I have already tried to upload img using input file method. But is it possible to upload a img src to spring controller?

```
<form method="POST" action="<c:url value='/upload' />"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Please select a file to upload : <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

I have already uploaded the image using file input tag.

```
  <form method="POST" action="<c:url value='/upload' />"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Please select a file to upload : <img src="demo.png"  />
        <input type="submit" value="upload" />
    </form>
```

Is it possible to do the upload using img tag without using file input tag.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert your data to `form` to be able to `submit` the data to a database or other uses.

Since `<img src="demo.png"  />` is just a static `html` code, form can´t get the `data` from that.

What you can do is to *pass* the `src` to `<input type="file" name="file" />`