# Directly opening the native image file upload dialog box in input file type tag

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile

**SUMMARY:**

I am designing an image upload for android chrome that has a separate mechanism for camera and dialog box select file. This is a UX decision in an attempt to make **action options** uniform across mobile devices accessing our website.

**DETAIL:**

We can force the camera through the following code

```html
<input type="file" capture="camera">
```

But for dialog box only upload, it seems its not possible to do this with the following:

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/jpg" multiple>
```

Opening it results to an option of camera & browse file.

[image: Android 9]

I only intend the dialog box for existing images, how do we force this in html5?

**DONE SO FAR:**

I looked into similar topics and even accepted solution in stackoverflow but they were **NOT** able to solve it. It always triggers the options as shown in the figure above.

[File dialog from JavaScript *without* <input>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8385758/file-dialog-from-javascript-without-input)

[Upload image tag source without using file input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37226061/upload-image-tag-source-without-using-file-input)

[How to disable/block a device from asking "Take photo" option during file uploads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53095463/how-to-disable-block-a-device-from-asking-take-photo-option-during-file-upload)